# Laying out form nicely

Tags: html, css, forms

Can somebody please give me a hint on how I should layout this form nice and neat. I've tried with lists, tables and divs but can't figure out which is best.

```html
Contact Information:
    <div class="formsubmit"><label>Name:</label><input type="name"  name="name" placeholder="John Doe" required />
 <label>Email:</label><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required /><span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>
 <label>Telephone:</label><input  type="tel" name="telephone" placeholder="##########" required pattern="[0-9]{10}"/>
      <span class="form_hint">Proper format "##########"</span>

      

 Type:
    <input type="checkbox" name="Type" value="condo" id="condo"><label>Condo</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Type" value="house" id="house"><label>House</label>


<input type="checkbox" name="title" value="freehold" id="freehold"><label>Freehold</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="title" value="leasehold" id="leasehold"><label>Leasehold</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="title" value="coop" id="coop"><label>Co-op:</label><a class="footnote">Check all that apply</a>
```

Comment: All of the types you listed can do this job and could look nice. It's just a matter of styling. Mess around with each one and find what is best for you. Tables maybe not the best one here just because it will limit you a little but any will do the job. Take a look on [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/search?q=form&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false) to give you ideas.

Comment: You're supposed to bring programming problems here. Code that doesn't work as expected or as you expect it to work. Your problem in this case is not a programming one. What you are looking for is a designer.

Comment: its  seems you are making a form, then you have to use `label`

Comment: As @Andrei says... stackoverflow is specifically for asking questions regarding specific technical problems.  This question does not fit that, and will result in personal opinion rather than a distinct solution.  Please try asking this on http://ux.stackexchange.com/ instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are making a `HTML form` then you have to write proper Semantic code. Use `form` tag with `fieldset` `legend` and use label with `for ="ID"`

Check the [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ruyuroqobi/1/edit?html,css,output).

```css
label, input{float:left; display:block;}
div{clear:left; padding:5px 0}
label{text-align:left; width:30%;}
```

```html
 <form action=" " method="post">
     <fieldset>
    <legend>Contact Information: </legend>
    
   <div> <label for="f_name">First Name </label>
     <input type="text" id="f_name" /></div>
    <div> <label for="l_name">Last Name </label>
      <input type="text"  id="l_name" /></div>
     </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: if your problem solved than you can close this answer by accepting the answer.